# Qual o real ganho em se usar MooTools!

Tags: mootools

Não somente na manipulação de elementos no Dom, mas sim em sua arquitetura orientada a objetos. Qual o real ganho em se usar ao invés do JQuery. Pegamos como exemplo um sistema de controle de estoque simples, com alguns cruds. Qual o uso do MooTools nesse caso que difere do JQuery.

Comment: Pergunta interessante e útil para distinguir estas duas grandes bibliotecas. Digo não só por ser colaborador do MooTools, mas porque muita gente não sabe a diferença entre as duas.

Comment: Favor não usar o campo de pergunta para outra finalidade que não seja expor sua duvida. Caso a pergunta seja fechada, você pode questionaros motivos no [meta]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe [um artigo excelente e muito completo](http://www.jqueryvsmootools.com/index_pt-br.html) sobre as diferênças entre MooTools e jQuery, traduzido pelo [Fábio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17791/fabiomcosta), atualmente um dos elementos do nucleo duro de desenvolvedores do Facebook.

O jQuery é basicamente uma biblioteca para o DOM. O MooTools tem inumeras ferramentas para programação, cálculos e tranformação de dados e é usado por muitos no servidor. Tem por exemplo Classes com mixins e herança (desde 2006!), melhoramentos em métodos essenciais como `typeOf`, métodos de Object e Array, etc.

Uma grande vantagem é que é modular. Enquanto que o jQuery é um ficheiro único, o MooTools é modular e permite [usar-se em módulos](http://mootools.net/core/builder) diminuíndo assim o tamanho do ficheiro que é carregado em todas as páginas.

Outra vantagem a meu ver, mas que pode ser um problema para quem não compreender, é que o MooTools estende o Prototype e mistura-se como JavaScript nativo. No jQuery tudo circula á volta da função `$()` e o que lhe é passado. Essa função retorna um objeto com métodos jQuery. No MooTools muitos dos métodos estão integrados na linguagem nativa.

A razão porque muita gente deixa de usar MooTools é porque o próprio JavaScript evoluiu. O MooTools criou métodos que completavam falhas importantes na linguagem, melhorou e corrigiu alguns métodos nativos e mais tarde com ES5 e ES6 esses métodos, com os mesmos nomes foram implementados nativamente. Assim nalguns casos o código já lá estava pois o MooTools estende a linguagem nativa. No caso do jQuery, agora que o ES5 tem `.forEach`, `.map` e `.filter` esses métodos são desnecessários mas para mudar código jQuery para métodos nativos dá demasiado trabalho.

Comment: Só uma nota: jQuery é DOM e Requests (ajax) também e outro adendo, ele circula a volta de `$.` além de `$()`, mas não é muito padronizado nesse caso  =)

Comment: Gosto muito do MooTools, faz tempo que não uso, essa pergunta me despertou a vontade de tentar usa-la +1

Comment: @Sergio Conseguiria demostrar um exemplo pratico do uso de MooTools, sem ser uma manipulação de Dom?

Comment: @Matheus para além de `Class` que sem dúvida foi a jóia da coroa do MooTools, dá uma olhada aos métodos de [Object](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Types/Object) e de [Array](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Types/Array). Praticamente todos esses métodos são para facilitar trabalhar com objetos, com dados, para programação no verdadeiro sentido da palavra.